# In Ember.js, what is the difference between [] and Ember.A([])?

Tags: ember.js

While looking through apps written with Ember.js, I noticed that sometimes arrays are defined with a call to `Ember.A()` and sometimes array literals are used. When I ran `Ember.A([1])` in the browser console, the return value looks just like an array and arrays created using array literals had the Ember.js methods `pushObject` and friends. Is the call to `Ember.A()` just a way to define an `Ember.Array` when you don't use prototype extensions? Otherwise are arrays all created equal?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your question contains the correct answer: `Ember.A()` just a way to define an [`Ember.Array`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html) when you have turned off the prototype extensions. You'll notice that Ember's internal code always uses `Ember.A()`.

Comment: The prototype extensions can be disabled by setting `ENV.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES = false` before loading Ember. They're enable by default.

Comment: how do you create and Ember.A() of length 6?

Comment: probably better as a new question, but it's: `Ember.A(new Array(6))`

Comment: Also note that within an Ember app, just defining `myArray = []` ember will beef it up to become an Ember.A() be default unless you do `window.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES = false;` as @JoLiss has mentioned. http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/